# Multiple sliding divs on website

Tags: jquery, html, nav

I am trying to design a nav for my page and I am wondering if anyone knows how to create sliding divs that come from the top, left, right, and bottom of page only when the corresponding button(top, left, right, bottom) is pressed? Can you help?

Here is the code I am trying. I can get the first slide to work, but trying multiple slides has gotten me confused:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var $marginLefty = $('#slidemarginleft2 div.inner');
$marginLefty.css({
  marginLeft: $marginLefty.outerWidth() + 'px',
  display: 'block'
});


$('#slidemarginleft2 button').click(function() {
  $marginLefty.animate({
    marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
    $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
  });
});
  }); 

$(document).ready(function() {
 var $marginTopy = $('#slidemargintop div.topinner');
$marginTopy.css({
  marginTop: $marginTopy.outerWidth() + 'px',
  display: 'block'
});


$('#slidemargintop button').click(function() {
  $marginTopy.animate({
    marginTop: parseInt($marginTopy.css('marginTop'),10) == 0 ?
    $marginTopy.outerWidth() : 0
  });
});

}); 

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.slide {
background-color: #FFFFCC;
border: 1px solid #999999;
height: 1000px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background-image: url(images/1px.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
.slide .inner {
background-color: #44CC55;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
color: #333333;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;

}

.slide1 .topinner {
background-color: blue;
top: 0;
left: 0;
color: #FFF;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;

}
.slide button {
margin: 0.7em 0 0 0.7em;
}

.slide1 button {
margin: 0.7em 0 0 0.7em;
}

.js #slidebottom .inner {
display: none;
}
</style>

</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">

<div class="slide" id="slidemarginleft2">
    <button>right</button>
    <button>top</button>
    <div class="inner"><button>close</button>Animate this element's margin-left style property(hidden)</div>
    <div class="topinner"><button>close</button>Animate this element's margin-left style property(hidden)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide1" id="slidemargintop">
    <button>top</button>
    <div class="topinner"><button>close</button>Animate this element's margin-left style property(hidden)</div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try jquery .slideDown() .slideUp()

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/